# When starting gameplay at a level higher than level one, how much gold/magic items do you start with?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

For a campaign that I have upcoming I am planning on having the characters start on level 3 or 4. I know for a fact that when starting a campaign from level 1 all PCs start with 100 gold, and as there are rules for making stats while starting at a higher level I'm assuming that somewhere there are rules for how much money those characters start with that's higher than 100, or they're entitled to some amount of magic items, but I am unsure of what that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When starting at a level higher than 1 players should each have the folloing:

> One magic item of their level
>   One magic item of their level -1
>   One magic item of their level +1
>   Gold to buy other items equal to an item of their level -1

(DMG p143)

Comment: **If** you're using the rarity rules, the items the players start with can be common or uncommon, but they can only use the gold to buy common items.